# To get the row number in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a gridview in which I have set datasource as a datatable. Whatever update I make to the gridview, it should reflect only in the datatable and not to the database. When I click update, I have to get the row number of a particular row which I want to update. How can I get the row number in rowupdating event of gridview in order to update the datatable? Suppose I have a datakey and if I get that unique id, how can I update the datatable which is the datasource?  Can anybody help?

Comment: can you put your code of grid view ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to get the row id of your updated row :

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
  string id = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString(); 
}
```

Maybe you want only the **e.RowIndex**. But the above code returns the specified unique data key for the row.

Answer (score 0):

If there is sorting applied then the row numbers in gridview and datatable won't match.

So if you try to update with the row number in gridview it may end up in incorrect values.

The updation should be based on a **unique ID** in the gridview datasource.

Comment: if soting is not there how can i get rownumber

Answer (score 0):

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Slno">
     <ItemTemplate>
     <div style="margin-top: 0px; color: black;">
     <asp:Label ID="txtid" runat="server" Font-Size="8.5pt" ForeColor="#000f9f" Text='<%# Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>'></asp:Label>
     </div>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="30px" />
     </asp:TemplateField>

protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
Label id  = (Label) GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].findcontrol("slno");
}
```