# GridView Get the row number containing a value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple code that displays the results with a simple thank you
I just want to fetch the row number that contains a specific value, knowing that the value is unique
For example, the owner id is 3, who got 939119, falls in row number 7
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8MZq.jpg)

```
    GridView1.DataSource = dt; 
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "CRPoints DESC";
GridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;      
GridView1.DataBind(); 
string idcc = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[3].ToString(); 
Label1.Text = idcc;
```

idcc = 7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To get the row number in gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258736/to-get-the-row-number-in-gridview)

Answer (score 0):

I would assume a typical setup is you have a GV. You load it up with data.

Then say on a row click, you want to get information about that row.

So, let's do this with a simple grid.

Our GV markup is thus this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVHotels" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover" 
    DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="40%"  >
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName"    HeaderText="First Name"  HeaderStyle-Width="100" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName"     HeaderText="Last Name"   HeaderStyle-Width="100" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName"    HeaderText="Hotel Name"  HeaderStyle-Width="120"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="City"         HeaderText="City" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Description"  HeaderText="Province" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="hotel as text box">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server" Text="<%# Eval("HotelName") %>" >
            </asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="cmdView" runat="server" Text="Row Click" CssClass="btn" 
                OnClick="cmdView_Click" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

So, two things you have to learn or remember:

To get a databound field from the GV, you use .Cells[] collection (starting at 0 for the first column.

To get a "control" you dropped into the GV, you have to use FindControl.

And to use a plain Jane button or drop down, or ANY standard asp.net control in the GV, you have to "wrap" it as the above markup shows (inside of a "TemplateField", and then inside of "ItemTemplate".

So, often you just use "BoundField", but often you can (and will want to) use a standard control in the grid row.

A great example in above is the placing of a plain Jane button click in the row (as per above rules).

So, we have this code to load the GV:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblhotelsA ORDER BY HotelName";

        GVHotels.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL);
        GVHotels.DataBind();
        
    }
```

And now we have/see this:

[image]

So, now our button click (to get the one row we click on).

this:

```
protected void cmdView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Button cmdMyRowBtn = (Button)sender;
    GridViewRow MyRow = (GridViewRow)cmdMyRowBtn.NamingContainer;

    int PKID = (int)GVHotels.DataKeys[MyRow.RowIndex]["ID"];

    Debug.Print($"Row index click = {MyRow.RowIndex.ToString()}");
    Debug.Print($"Data base PK id = {PKID.ToString()}");

    // get a "databound" field  - use cells colleciton

    Debug.Print($"Hotel name from cells field = {MyRow.Cells[2].Text}");

    // get a tempatled column (those standard asp.net controls in the gv

    TextBox txtHotel = (TextBox)MyRow.FindControl("txtHotel");

    Debug.Print($"Hotel name from text box in gv = {txtHotel.Text}");

}
```

So, above, when you click, you can then do whatever you want. You can get values, take values and fill out some text boxes - do whatever.

The output from above click is this:

Output:

```
Row index click = 1
Data base PK id = 5
Hotel name from cells field = Inns of Banff
Hotel name from text box in gv = Inns of Banff
```

So, from above, you should be able to do quite much anything you want.

And of course like any developer, I get VERY tired VERY fast having to type connection string and code to get a data table from SQL. So I have this handy helper bit of code I used above.

```
DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
{
    DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
        }
    }
    return rstData;
}
```

(so adjust above to use your connection string)

So above should give you the building blocks you need.

So:

To get columns from a given GV row, use .cells[] collection.

To get "controls" you may well use in the GV, use find control.

To get row click, see the above button code.

With these 3 things, this should allow you to do just about anything you ever want to do with a GV.

## Edit: Get/find a rowindex on a column value - in this case ID

We want to search/find and obtain the row index from the GV for a given value in the GV - in this case, for a given "ID" value, we want the row index.

AGAIN, context matters. Maybe this is a row click in client side JavaScript code, but as the question is written, then we looking to find the row index for a given ID.

OK, this will work:

```
Function GetRowIndex(sFind As String, sKey As String, GV As GridView) As Integer


    For Each gRow As GridViewRow In GV.Rows
        If GV.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex).Item(sKey) = sFind Then
            Return gRow.RowIndex
        End If
    Next

    Return -1

End Function
```

So, there is no built in translation here.

The REAL issue, is when, where, why you want the row index based on say a given datakey. I been doing this for OVER 10 years, and have NEVER needed to do this.

In other words? DO NOT try and use the gridview as a database, or some "thing" that stores data - it is mostly for display, and if you need to search, then provide a grid search ability, and filter the results.

So, you can search values in the Grid, or values (not displayed) in datakeys.

So, this routine would return the row index for a given data key value. HOWEVER, do NOT just SHOVE general values into datakeys - in 99% of cases, datakeys is for the ONE database primary key value, and those values should NOT be exposed to the end user - they NEVER are to see the database key values - especially with web based software (too high of a security risk).

So, this routine would search datakeys:

```
Function GetRowIndex(sFind As String, sKey As String, GV As GridView) As Integer


    For Each gRow As GridViewRow In GV.Rows
        If GV.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex).Item(sKey) = sFind Then
            Return gRow.RowIndex
        End If
    Next

    Return -1

End Function
```

However, if the data is in the GV, then search that, and does not "needless" add the values to the datakeys (only have/place values in datakeys that you don't want to display or expose to the end user).

So, in above, I can do this:

```
    Dim sFindID As String
    sFindID = "5"

    Debug.Print($"Row index of given id {sFindID} = {GetRowIndex(sFindID, "ID", GVHotels)}")
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts and sharing of information
The user doesn't do any work, he just watches the results
There is no button or anything to press
I predetermine what values it watches
I just want to know the row number containing the value you specified earlier
The code I tried does not mean the result I want
I just need to know the row number

Comment: Do you need the rownumber for display, or do you want in code the row number for a given row? In code, to get the 4th row, and return row number, then you use GridView1.Rows[3].RowIndex, and the value of Rowindex will be 3 (it starts at 0).

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear in asking the question,
Thanks for trying to help me,
Number 3 is the account ID number,
I want to know the line number where this number is located,
The meaning I want to say: Tell me where is the ID = 3,
He told me: He was on Line = 7

Comment: Ok, so context matters. There is no built in search for datakeys - and is is VERY rare that you should need as such. In most cases, you want to query the database to get that value. Don't try and use the GV as a database!!! - see my edit, I show how you can get the rowindex for a given ID. But, for general searching of values? Don't search the GV, you filter or search against the database, display results in GV, and then let user select the value. So, as general rule, searching GV is a VERY bad idea. So your question is how to search the GV - and you should not if possible